# Export dataframes as separate files after using `np.array_split` in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

How can I export each dataframe with different name after using `np.array_split`?

I split my dataframe into multiple parts, let's say, 4 and I want to export them as separate dataframes with the corresponding name, for example, `df_split_1.csv`, `df_split_2.csv`, `df_split_3.csv`, `df_split_4.csv` and so on.

Clearly, I can do this with an approach of `df_split[1].to_csv(r'W:\...\df_split_1.csv')`, however, if I had 100 of these dataframes, doing this to each and one of them is not a long-term solution. So, the question is how can I split dataframe and export them as separate files?

My guess would be to create a loop that saves the files automatically, but I have not figured it out yet.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.read_file(r'W:\...\dataframe.csv')
df_split = np.array_split(df, 4)

df_split[0].to_csv(r'W:\...\df_split_1.csv')
df_split[1].to_csv(r'W:\...\df_split_2.csv')
df_split[2].to_csv(r'W:\...\df_split_3.csv')
df_split[3].to_csv(r'W:\...\df_split_4.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop with `enumerate`:

```
for i, v in enumerate(df_split, 1):
    v.to_csv(fr'W:\...\df_split_{i}.csv')
```

Comment: What does 1 mean in  enumerate(df_split, 1)?

Comment: @g12345kk It's the start value for iterator `i`, it starts from `1` index instead of `0`. More on documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate